# move certain columns to end using awk

Tags: awk

I have large tab delimited file with 1000 columns. I want to rearrange so that certain columns have to be moved to the end.

Could anyone help using awk

Example input:

```
1  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
```

Move columns 5,6,7,8 to the end.
Output:

```
1  2   3   4  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20   5   6   7   8
```

Comment: `cat foo|awk '{print $1 $2 $3 $4 $9 ....}`, basically.

Comment: @MarcB Never use  `cat` with programs that can read data itself, like `awk`.  `awk 'code' foo`

Comment: @MarcB thanks!! yes it can be done that way. But as i said i have hundreds of columns which is not feasible to specify all the columns with the way you suggested. I hope you got my point.

Comment: @user1779730 you're going to have to be a lot clearer. We cant help you write code to move `certain columns` without more information on how those `certain columns` will be identified.

Comment: Are there intentionally different amounts of white space between the columns? If so, how should this be dealt with?

Comment: @EdMorton post edited in the example

Comment: @TomFenech there are no intentional white spaces. it is a tab-delimited file

Comment: wrt `Move columns 5,6,7,8 to the end` - should those values be hard-coded in the script, passed in as a variable, read from line 1 of the input file, read from another file or something else. Really THINK about what it is you're posting - the better question you ask the better answer you will likely receive.

Comment: the example i provided is one line from a file. it has multiple such rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This prints columns 1 to `a`, then `b` to the last, and then columns `a+1` to `b-1`:

```
$ awk -v a=4 -v b=9 '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=i==a?b-a:1) {printf "%s\t",$i};for (i=a+1;i<b;i++) {printf "%s\t",$i};print""}' file
1       2       3       4       9       10      11      12      13      14      15      16
        17      18      19      20      5       6       7       8
```

The columns are moved in this way for every line in the input file, however many lines there are.

#### How it works

- `-v a=4 -v b=9`

  This defines the variables `a` and `b` which determine the limits on which columns will be moved.
- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=i==a?b-a:1) {printf "%s\t",$i}`

  This prints all columns except the ones from `a+1` to `b-1`.

  In this loop, `i` is incremented by one except when `i==a` in which case it is incremented by `b-a` so as to skip over the columns to be moved.  This is done with awk's ternary statement:

  ```
  i += i==a ? b-a : 1
  ```

  `+=` simply means "add to."  `i==a ? b-a : 1` is the ternary statement.  The value that it returns depends on whether `i==a` is true or false.  If it is true, the value before the colon is returned.  If it is false, the value after the colon is returned.
- `for (i=a+1;i<b;i++) {printf "%s\t",$i}`

  This prints columns `a+1` to `b-1`.
- `print""`

  This prints a newline character to end the line.

#### Alternative solution that avoids `printf`

This approach assembles the output into the variable `out` and then prints with a plain `print` command, avoiding `printf` and the need for percent signs:

```
awk -v a=4 -v b=9 '{out="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=i==a?b-a:1) out=out $i"\t";for (i=a+1;i<b;i++) out=out $i "\t";print out}' file
```

Comment: I have a small issue with printf "%s\n" in the code. I am using this code in a python module which treats %s as string. Is there any alternative to replace the '%s' in the printf statement? I tried using normal print but couldn't succeed. Could you help

Comment: @user1779730 No problem.  See the update which uses no `%` symbols and avoids `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to rearrange 2 columns (`$5` become `$20` and `$20` become `$5`) the rest stay unchanged :

```
$ awk '{x=$5; $5=$20; $20=x; print}' file.txt
```

for 4 columns :

```
$ awk '{
    x=$5; $5=$20; $9=x;
    y=$9; $9=$10; $10=y;
    print
}' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks!! well it works on re-arranging two columns with each other. However, my query is to re-arrange multiple columns as explained in the initial post

Comment: Added an example for 4 columns, feel free to follow the logic to move more columns

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ f[5];f[6];f[7];f[8] } \
{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(!(i in f)) printf "%s\t", $i; \
for(c in f) printf "%s\t", $c; printf "\n"} ' file
```

It's splitted in 3 parts:

1. The `BEGIN{}` part determines which field should be moved to the end. The indexes of the array `f` are moved. In the example it's 5, 6, 7 and 8.
2. Cycle trough every field (doesn't matter if there are 1000 fields or more) and check if they are in the array. If not print them.
3. Now we need the skipped fields. Cycle trough the `f` array and print those values.

Answer (score 0):

Another way in awk
Switch last A-B with last N fields

```
awk -vA=4 -vB=8 '{x=B-A;for(i=A;i<=B;i++){y=$i;$i=$(t=(NF-x--));$t=y}}1' file
```

Put N rows from end into positon A

```
awk -vA=3 -vB=8 '{split($0,a," ");x=A++;while(x++<B)$x=a[NF-(B-x)];while(B++<NF)$B=a[A++]}1' file
```